# How to wrap UL list - LIs on new line with css

Tags: css

Here in the image below the list is going out of the screen. I need to block the width of the ul. Width applied but going out of the ul width.
Current CSS Used:

```
.menu ul{
width:100%;
max-width:100%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this

```
.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Decent support](http://caniuse.com/inline-block) and here's a nice [round up](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/inline-blocks/).

If there's a

- `margin-left` try not to set the width to `100%`, but rather `100% - margin-left-value`
- `padding-left` use [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/)

If you don't have to support older browsers or are fine with loading a polyfill, flexbox model would do the job.

Answer (score 1):

display: inline;
or 
display: inline-block;

Both works.